# What's the fastest way to move builds from world to world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit, mcedit

I know I can use mcedit, but I was wondering if there was a faster way with world edit to copy builds from one world to another.

Comment: uhmm.. something like `//copy` and `//schem save mcedit <name>`? :)

Comment: Faster than what? Without that detail, the question logically makes no sense and also practically, because nobody knows if they can just tell you the standard way or if it has to be something else.

Comment: @Fabian faster than mcedit as mentioned

Comment: I read it as "faster than X, but not MCEdit because I don't like MCEdit" or whatever. But then the question becomes: Are you asking for a way to do it faster than you did so far in general (then you shouldn't restrict it to Worldedit) or are you asking for a way to do it faster using Worldedit than it would be using MCEdit (which would be weirdly specific)?

Comment: @Fabian I ment faster then going to mcedit making a schematic from one world opening a new world putting it in then closing mcedit like can I just get a clipboard that transfers world to world?

Comment: @Fabian *(...) faster way using world edit (...) other than using mcedit* is specific enough imho. OP is clearly asking for a world edit solution to c&p stuff from one world to another.

Answer (score 1):

The WorldEdit solution is pretty easy, since WorldEdit supports mcedit schematics and we can make use of these...

1. `//copy` (as you would usually do)
2. `//schem save mcedit <name>` ( I used "bunny" here, no extension needed)

[image]

3. Locate the Schematic file in your *WorldEdit/schematics* directory. It should have the name you gave it plus the *.schematic* extension.
4. Copy that file over to the same directory of the target world
5. `//schem load mcedit <name>` will load it into the clipboard

[image]

6. `//paste`

[image]

**Remember**: Just like with normal c&p it will remember your position when you copied it and paste it relatively to your position when using `//paste`. Make sure to stand on the right position when pasting it. Standing on the ground right next to the structure when copying it is usually a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

dly's answer does work but if you want to move builds without using world edit, another way is to use structure blocks

Comment: Generally speaking, it is better to say, "x could work, and here is how you use it" instead of just saying "try x".